# vba scraping code does not recognize tags or classes

Tags: vba, getelementsbytagname

Dear stackoverflowers,

I am new into VBA and i try to get some data from a password protected website. 
Filling in the username and password and clicking on the submit button works fine. Then, another page opens where i have to click on several 'buttons' but i dont understand why its not working. 
i try to click on the following icon.

```
<td class="menuitem"> <a title="Klik hier voor de dienst Kadaster-on-line" class="navig" onmouseover="return s_('Kadaster-on-line')" onmouseout="return s_()" href="https://kadaster-on-line.kadaster.nl/default.asp" target="_parent">Kadaster-on-line</a>
```

the first part of the code works so far

```
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://mijn.kadaster.nl/security/login.jsp"
Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("gebruikerscode")
    HTMLInput.Value = "username"
IE.Document.forms("myform").elements("wachtwoord").Value = "password"
    IE.Document.forms("myform").elements("inloggen").Click

Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

but the second part does not work. first I tried to figure it out by getelementsbyclassname but i guess it should be working by tagname

```
Set HTMLAs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    'For Each HTMLA In HTMLAs
        Debug.Print HTMLAs.Length
    'Next
```

it seems like the code does not recognize the tagname "td"
i also tried the codes with classname "menuitem"

can anybody please help me?

kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-execute

```
Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
```

after loading a new page. Otherwise HTMLDoc still points to the previous page (which is no longer available...)